# Impact of extra unused code from overloaded or templated function?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, overloading

I am writing an interface class for point cloud registration using the PCL library. This means that I need to use its classes which are for the most part templated. However, I will not know the type of data the user wants to use before run-time. I'm ok with having to store a couple possibly null pointers to data and objects that I might not need to use because they are too few to have a meaningful impact on memory usage and there will only be one object of my class.

However, I will also have to duplicate some of my code one way or another, because it is going to use the underlying templated code of PCL. For example I might need the following

```
template<typename PointT>
process_cloud(pcl::PointCloud<PointT> &input_cloud);
```

I'm going to need 3-4 instantiations of this function (and a couple others) to be able to handle types unkown until run-time. However, I'm going to end up only using one of them. If these functions are non-trivial in size, what sort of impact can I expect on performance?

If it is non-negligible, how can I aleviate it? I tried to figure out ways that don't need duplicate code but I can't find a way to handle templated code polymorphically without writing templated code of my own.

If I have to make do with this design, is there any way to optimize the memory layout as to minimize the performance hit of cache misses? For example can I guarantee that my universally-needed functions will be close together and not watered-down by the potentially never called instantiations?

I thought about templating the whole class. This will make code more local because each isntantiation will group together the functions that will be called in tandem (same data type). It will also introduce more code bloat by creating copies of code that didn't need to be templated. To avoid this extra bloat, the best I can come up with is conceptually this:

```
template<typename PointT>
class Processor {
    public:
        process_cloud(pcl::PointCloud<PointT> &input_cloud);
        ...
}

class Interface {
    public:
        // ...
        // bunch of common functions
        // ...

        // Instantiations I'm going to need. Pointers to save space.
        // Could also be std::optional if pointers turn out to be unneeded
        std::unique_ptr<Processor<pcl::PointXYZ>> p1;
        ...
}
```

This should produce a memory layout where the common functions are grouped together because they are defined in `Interface`. Every point type also has the functions used on it also grouped together because they are defined in separate classes. It's a little less readable, though. Any cleaner ways to help the compiler understand that template instantiations with the same argument are going to be used in tandem and should be local? Will it maybe realize and do it automatically?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the *normal* approach is causing you significant performance problems? Avoid premature optimization.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to give some good advice, but I know not to obsess over it and only asked because it is an interesting question. Unavoidably, something similar is going to crop up in performance critical code with multiple function calls and therefore it requires an answer regardless of whether it will be significant in my current project.

Comment: It's not as interesting a question as you might think. The compiler doesn't just generate code for all the member functions one after the other, and the linker doesn't just put them in a row. There is generally only very limited benefit to having related functions "more local". And rearranging your code like that is *not* guaranteed to make the compiler/linker do what you want (among other reasons, because they're trying to do what's best, not what you told them to do).

Comment: I appreciate that you're interested in this, but I'd suggest attacking it by learning how the compiler and linker work in general, rather than by investigating this particular use case. (It's not going to be a particularly instructive one, except maybe about COMDATs.)

Comment: If you have a source for all that, please post it as an answer because it's exactly what I'm asking about; especially the part about a class's implementation not necessarily being local.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with it by putting an explicit instantiation in separate compilation units vs putting them all in the same compilation unit.

My guess is the difference won't be large as the only difference would be in ITLB misses.

Fewer in the separate case due to the code being more local.
You will get slightly more total code but if you only use one instance the rest should not influence the runtime as it never pollute the caches and might be swapped out at some time.

If the compiler and linker doesn't decide that they want to sort the functions after the 3rd letter in their mangled names or for some slightly better reason.